# How to copy table with contents?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I use Microsoft SQL Server2012 Managment Studio and would like to know how to copy a table. Why this sql query does not works. It doesn't copy the contents.

```
insert into dbo.street_copy
select * from dbo.street
```

Comment: dbo.street_copy this table exists in your database?? if no then you need to go for SELECT * INTO clause else if it exists in your db then plz share the table structures..

Answer (score 3):

use this syntax:

```
 select * 
 INTO dbo.street_copy 
 from dbo.street
```

Keep in mind that new table is missing keys, indexes and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to get table with its content.

Step 1: Right click on database > Tasks > Generate Scripts.

Step 2: Click next if information window pops up.

Step 3: Select table name[image]

Step 4: Click on Advance and Types of data to script [image]

Step 5: Click next > Finish

Answer (score 0):

Utilize SQL's Import Export feature.

This may take a few more steps but not only will it copy rows and columns, but stored procedures, indexes and other objects that would not be copied with `insert into` statements.